# Are AMD Crossfire multi-monitor restrictions active at all times or only when in a full screen game?

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst, amd-graphics-card, crossfire

I'm considering a dual graphics card setup for 6 monitors. I'll have two identical cards, AMD Radeons, so I'd like to benefit from a Crossfire setup. I've read Crossfire will disable the outputs on the secondary card, but I haven't found anything that clearly states if this happens *at all times* or only during a full screen 3D game.

In short, I'd like 6 monitors while working and if I launch a full screen game it's perfectly fine for three monitors to turn off. Does Crossfire work this way, or will I have to configure my system with it normally disabled in Catalyst and manually enable it before launching a game?

Answer (score 1):

The article
[How to Configure Discrete Graphics Cards to Run in AMD CrossFire™ Mode](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/dh2-018)
just says:

> Displays connected to secondary GPUs are automatically disabled; to enable these displays, AMD CrossFire support must first be disabled.

Full screen is not mentioned at all, so is not implicated.
To use the secondary monitor would require disabling CrossFire,
which you can do in the Catalyst Control Center.

Comment: Yes, but it also says "AMD CrossFire™ requires the application to run in exclusive full screen mode when using DirectX® 9, 10, 11 and OpenGL APIs." Does that mean CrossFire is not really enabled until it is in that situation? Or maybe it's always "active" (until manually disabled like you suggested) but only DX12 games can use it in a window?

Comment: I take this as a requirement for the application to be able to use CrossFire. I don't think that CrossFire will disable itself system-wide because of one application that is not full screen. As there will always be some such application in the background, CrossFire would be disabled for ever. So this cannot be the case.